# How was Law's fever cured by eating Ope Ope fruit?

Tags: one-piece

I saw the episode in which Law had a fever and was about to die.

Just by eating the Ope Ope fruit his fever was cured.

As I understood, it makes you a genius doctor, but how was he cured instantly?

Comment: I just wanna know... You up to that arc and yo name "Germa Vinsmoke"? :)

Comment: I'm watching it @TGamer

Comment: @TGamer +1 for closing the quote before the question mark.

Answer (score 4):

Eating Ope Ope no Mi does not guarantee a **cure** *per se*. Remember the scene when Law tried to heal Rosinante? Rosinante ***laughed*** at him and said it doesn't work that way. Ope Ope no Mi is simply a tool/means to heal someone.

Law had to **study** being a doctor and medicine to cure himself with said **knowledge**.

As the wiki has said,

> The Ope Ope no Mi is a Paramecia-type Devil Fruit that allows its user to create a spherical space or "room", in which the user has **complete control** over the placement and orientation of the objects inside, making the user a Free Modification Human (改造自在人間 Kaizō Jizai Ningen?).

Like the description has said, the Ope Ope no Mi is indeed a powerful devil fruit but more powerful if the user has **medical knowledge**.

> The Ope Ope no Mi has been described as having "**miraculous**" properties, having the *ability to cure any kind of illness*, but at the same time still **requires some extent of medical knowledge in order to be utilized effectively** as the fruit's influence only **bends** but **not fully defy** biological aspects of those recipient to its life-saving applications and its miraculous healing is actually **focused on spatially extracting disease-causing impurities such as bacteria and viruses directly out of the patients' bodies**. As such, if a *doctor of prodigious* **medical expertise** were to obtain this fruit's power, their medical abilities would be second to none.

Comment: I recommend also googling questions and reading the wiki to find the answer to for future reference. :)

Comment: But he need to perform the operation then how was his fever cured just by eating the fruit.

Comment: As I've said, it wasn't shown. He cured himself _off-screen_. Eating the Ope Ope no Mi _does_ not _INSTA-CURE_ you to any disease. You must have at least basic medical knowledge to use it. It's near-useless if you don't have medical knowledge. Also, Law read a lot of his father's books when he was young so he may have *some* medical knowledge he got from it to cure himself.

Comment: A great analogy would be giving an uneducated person a book. If he can't read, that book is basically useless. So he has to learn how to read first to fully utilize the gift given to him.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has nothing to do with the fruit.

I think a more logical reasoning would be that when he saw Corazon's body, his adrenaline levels pumped up a lot. Even in real life (if you want to relate) when you are really sick and can't get out of bed, you could get up and run if something like that happens in front of you. In this case, Law developed a liking to Corazon, and seeing get all bloody like that could have killed him. By now you know how Luffy felt in the Marineford arc, especially at *that moment* (you know what). As a kid, it is a shock he didn't faint or something. Not to mention he was sick.

Comment: For anyone who thinks this answer is low quality, please comment why.